# RAM problems...the slot closer to CPU is working the second one is not working

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have 1 x 4 GB RAM pad and 2 slots. If switched to another slot computer restarts after 10 sec and does that on and on. Where is the problem?
 
Today i also got new better 2 X4 GB RAM pads. Same problem, in the first slot pads are working but when I put pad to second slot still the same problem computer restarts every 10 sec. Monitor is black so I can't do anything in that 10 sec. Is there problem with the second slot if the first one is working and what kind?

Comment: I had a similar problem, where both slots were working with 2 x 2GB but not with 2 x 4GB. I have tried all sorts of things but nothing worked :(

Comment: I think that the second slot is broken or something?

Comment: If you have guarantee for motherboard I suggest you replace it. I don't know if it's broken because just like I've said it worked with 2 x 2GB for me, so maybe it's the same case with your motherboard.

Comment: i think that guarantee is passed :/ i have B75MA-E33 if that helps

Comment: Try updating motherboard to latest BIOS and clean the ram slot carefully  with brush maybe is dirty

Answer (score -1):

It is actually typical for a motherboard to require certain slots to be populated first when filling the board with RAM.  You cannot simply place a single stick of RAM in any open slot.

This means that while you could place 4GB in slot 1 and 4GB in slot 2, you would need to place 4GB in slot 1 if only one RAM module was being used.  If you attempt to put one module in slot 2, the motherboard will not POST or boot.

Comment: I placed 1x4GB and another 1x4GB first at the first slot and then on second but the same happens